# 'execfile' not defined in apache2 config

Tags: python, django, apache, sys

I want to deploy two different Django apps in the same host with the different virtual environment (python2.7 and python 3.6). I had followed the tutorial https://www.thecodeship.com/deployment/deploy-django-apache-virtualenv-and-mod_wsgi/ to deploy. one of my WSGI scripts is

```
import os
import sys
import site


site.addsitedir('~/.virtualenvs/myprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

sys.path.append('/home/django_projects/MyProject')
sys.path.append('/home/django_projects/MyProject/myproject')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'

activate_env=os.path.expanduser("~/.virtualenvs/myprojectenv/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

when I run apache server I get an error ---> `Nameserver: name 'execfile' is not defined`

When I searched for this error I found execfile is not supported in Python 3.X. But I have 2 Django app to deploy. Please help me to find the solution. Is there any detail you need let me know

Comment: how to change my execfile to exec @Daniel

Comment: Did you read the linked duplicate, which explains exactly how to do that?

Comment: I tried this execfile(open(activate_env).read(), dict(__file__=activate_env)) .but exception occured @DanielRoseman

Comment: Like Daniel says: change `execfile` to `exec` like is said in the other answer.

Comment: I changed exec(open(activate_env).read(), dict(__file__=activate_env)) ... I get error not iteratable...